# SAML - Open Login

Tags: saml, onelogin

We are using a ecommerce plataform that can integrate with SAML protocol. They just need the authorization url. Do I need to create an App on One Login?
Or I could user a custom app integration?

Can you provide me some guidelines

Answer (score 1):

What's the platform?

It may already exist in the OneLogin SAML catalog (we have a few thousand apps) but if not, please see https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector

Additionally, you (or the Platform vendor) can always contact us to see about getting an official connector added to the catalog if it's not already there.

Regardless, your best bet is OneLogin support as this isn't really a development question.